# Populate Wicket DropDownChoice with Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket

I have a form in Wicket with several DropDownChoice components. For one of these DropDownChoice components, I would like to keep it disabled at first and then enable it and populate it with the output of a Java function that takes as input the value of another DropDownChoice component. How would I do that with Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.ChoicePage, it does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, to ajaxify the drop down choices, you need to add `AjaxaFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour("onchange")`.

Then if you need to populate the choice list of one drop down, in other drop down's selection change, then you need to write it in the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour("onchange") {}` method.

Inside the method, you need to build the list and add it to the other drop down by setChoices(list);
As all these are done in ajax, you need to add the drop down to the ajax target by `target.addComponent(doprdown2);`

As the component is going to be operated in ajax you need to do the following to the second drop down

```
dropdown2.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

Full Example:

```
DropdownChoice ddc1 = new ("id1", model1, list1);
DropdownChoice ddc2 = new ("id2", model2, list2);
ddc2.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(tag);

ddc1.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour("onchange"){
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    // Build the list2
    ddc2.setChoices(list2);

    target.addComponent(ddc2);
}
});
```